# PHP: Why was the `default` parameter RFC rejected?

Tags: php

My apologies if stackoverflow isn't the right place for this.  I'm just trying to figure out why the PHP team would vote *No* on this RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/skipparams

Basically it is suggesting the following code be valid:

```
function foo($a, $b = "2", $c = "3") {
    echo "$a $b $c";
}

foo(1, default, 5); // prints "1 2 5"
```

This looks like a great idea to me... why reject it?

Comment: Yes, SO is not place for questions like these.

Comment: Where would have been?

Comment: email it to Author maybe? stas@php.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [named_params](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params) is a better solution (though this RFC has stalled for 3 years now).

```
htmlspecialchars($string, default, default, false);
// vs
htmlspecialchars($string, double_encode => false);
```

Reasons quoted from the [`php-internals` mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=internals%40lists.php.net&q=subject:%22[PHP-DEV]+[RFC]+[VOTE]+Parameter+skipping+RFC%22&o=newest&f=1):

> Basically, even though not having to specify the default-value for some 
>   parameters could be useful in some situations, **this approach doesn't 
>   feel right and we would really prefer something like named-parameters** 
>   (even if this RFC is not incompatible with named-parameters and they 
>   most likely won't make it for PHP 7.0).

One of the downvoters, @philstu, [also blogged](https://philsturgeon.uk/php/2015/03/15/php-7-feature-freeze/#skipping-optional-parameters-for-functions),

> While I am glad Stas went to the trouble of making this, I am so much more glad that people downvoted it. **It’s a band aid solution to named parameters, and I really hope we see them for later versions of PHP 7.x.**